# I Working around Stellar Multisig and I am getting

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory, multi-sig, signer

````
    at Function.setOptions (C:\Users\user\Desktop\multisig\node_modules\stellar-base\lib\operations\set_options.js:137:13)
    at setMultisigOnEmekaAccount (C:\Users\user\Desktop\multisig\multisig.js:30:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)``

here is my code

```const { Server, Networks, TransactionBuilder, Operation, Keypair } = require('stellar-sdk');
const { emeka, ade} = require("./accounts.json");

const server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");

const setMultisigOnEmekaAccount = async () => {
    const extraSigner = {
        signer: {
            ed2551PublicKey: ade.publicKey,
            weight: 1
        }
    };

    const thresholds = {
        masterWeight: 2,
        lowThreshold: 2,
        medThreshold: 3,
        highThreshold: 3,
    };

    const txOptions ={
        fee: await server.fetchBaseFee(),
        networkPassphrase: Networks.TESTNET
    };

    const emekaAccount = await server.loadAccount(emeka.publicKey);

    const multiSigTx = new TransactionBuilder(emekaAccount, txOptions)
        .addOperation(Operation.setOptions(thresholds))
        .addOperation(Operation.setOptions(extraSigner))
        .setTimeout(0)
        .build();
    
    multiSigTx.sign(Keypair.fromSecret(emeka.secret));

    await server.submitTransaction(multiSigTx);
};

setMultisigOnEmekaAccount()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Signed");
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    });```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the typo in the `signer` object: signer.ed2551**9**PublicKey